# How to combine group by, join, COUNT, SUM and subquery clauses in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure how to write the SQL query for the following problem:

There are two tables, Worker and Product (one worker can make many products) which I describe in this link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yk2vKKmUEyuN-QfgTEbmF4suHFtuDkkrsUf-wqvOoKQ/edit?fbclid=IwAR3ipjwNrfhGXg3fCyAri4tD1Q4WqWuKVAqagvbsZg9Sn1myDwkWbWcl_6E#gid=0

The calculation of the total salary of a worker at month x is as follows
totalSalary = salaryPerMonth + SUM(salaryPerProduct * COUNT(pid))

I want to use join statement (regardless of INNER JOIN, LEFT, OR RIGHT JOIN) combined with group by clause to solve this problem but my statements are wrong.

Expect a specific SQL statement in this case.

[I hope to be able to express my ideas in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2DaV.png)

---

UPDATE: my picture quality is not good so i will repost my picture on this link[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2DaV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please edit your question to include your table definitions, any code, and data as text in the question instead of posting links to images and external documents.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidelines on asking questions which will better help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One example of how you might improve the question and avoid it being closed:

**Issue:**

I am trying to write a SQL query to calculate the total salary for workers for a given month `X`. There are two tables: [Worker] and [Product]. One worker can make many products.

| wid | wname | salaryPerMonth | salaryPerProduct | phoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr A | 500 | 5 |  |
| 2 | Mr B | 100 | 30 |  |
| 3 | Mr C | 200 | 20 |  |

| pid | pname | manufacturedDate | wid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A | 2013-12-01 | 1 |
| 2 | Product B | 2013-12-09 | 1 |
| 3 | Product C | 2013-09-08 | 1 |
| 4 | Product D | 2013-01-30 | 2 |
| 5 | Product E | 2013-09-20 | 2 |
| 6 | Product F | 2013-12-23 | 3 |

The "Total Salary" of a worker for month X is calculated as follows:

```
SalaryPerMonth + 
   ( SalaryPerProduct * 
     Number of Products for Month
   )
```

**Expected Results:** (December 2013)

| wid | wname | salaryPerMonth | salaryPerProduct | totalSalary | ** Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr A | 500 | 5 | 510 | = 500 + (5*2) |
| 2 | Mr B | 100 | 30 | 100 | = 100 + (30*0) |
| 3 | Mr C | 200 | 20 | 220 | = 200 + (20*1) |

**Actual Results**

I've tried this query

```
SELECT W.wid, W.wname, W.phoneNumber, W.salaryPerMonth, W.salaryPerProduct, (W.salaryPerMonth - SUM(W.salaryPerMonth*COUNT(p.pid))) AS Total 
FROM   Worker W INNER JOIN Product P ON p.Wid = W.wid 
WHERE  MONTH(P.manufacturedDate) = 12 
GROUP BY W.wid, W.wname, W.phoneNumber, W.salaryPerMonth, W.salaryPerProduct
```

.. but am getting the error below:

```
Msg 130 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

---

Here is my [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf161d6e84ac7ba815723682911af2af)

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  pid int 
  , pname varchar(40)
  , manufacturedDate date
  , wid int 
);

CREATE TABLE Worker (
  wid int 
  , wname varchar(40)
  , salaryPerMonth int 
  , salaryPerProduct int
  , phoneNumber varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO Product(pid, pname, manufacturedDate, wid)
VALUES 
(1,'Product A','2013-12-01',1)
,(2,'Product B','2013-12-09',1)
,(3,'Product C','2013-09-08',1)
,(4,'Product D','2013-01-30',2)
,(5,'Product E','2013-09-20',2)
,(6,'Product F','2013-12-23',3)
;

INSERT INTO Worker (wid, wname, salaryPerMonth,salaryPerProduct)
VALUES 
(1,'Mr A', 500, 5)
,(2, 'Mr B', 100, 30)
,(3,'Mr C', 200, 20)
;
```